# Accessing json elements gives undefined error

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "list": {
        "q": "raw",
        "sr": "28",
        "ds": "Standard Reference",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 1,
        "total": 1391,
        "group": "",
        "sort": "n",
        "item": [
            {
                "offset": 0,
                "group": "Poultry Products",
                "name": "Chicken, broilers or fryers, dark meat, thigh, meat only, raw",
                "ndbno": "05096",
                "ds": "SR"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I try to access elements in this json i keep getting undefined error... I already checked if the JSON is valid and yes the json is valid! 
Maybe I am accesing the JSON wrong? The JSON is stored in a variable called result. This is how I tried so far:

```
console.log(result.list.ds);
```

I also tried:

```
console.log(result["0"].list.ds);
```

but both solutions give me the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ds' of undefined

Why is this happening? Any tips or suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Its working. result.list.ds is fetching Standard Reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your JSON stored in your variable as a string? Try:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(result).list.ds)
```

The reason I ask is that the text `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ds' of undefined` tells me that your `result` variable does not have a `list` property, which your JSON clearly would if it were an object, but it most assuredly would not if you had accidentally forgotten to parse your JSON string.

Comment: yes this worked :D, may i ask what JSON.parse exactly does?

Comment: `JSON.parse` takes a string of text in JSON format (think `var string = '{"key":"value"}'`) and converts it into bunch of nested JS objects (think `var object = { key: "value" }`). The difference in the outer quotes is *crucial*. `typeof string` will return `'string'` in this case, while `typeof object` will return `'object'`, meaning `object` has properties while `string` just has an array of characters. `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` allow you to convert between these string and object forms.

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` is valid and if you are accessing the `ds` property inside `list` object. Your syntax `console.log(result.list.ds);` is correct.

But, If you are trying to access the `ds` property inside the `item` array then you have to iterate the array to get the `ds` property.

**DEMO**

```js
var result = {
 "list": {
  "q": "raw",
  "sr": "28",
  "ds": "Standard Reference",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 1,
  "total": 1391,
  "group": "",
  "sort": "n",
  "item": [{
   "offset": 0,
   "group": "Poultry Products",
   "name": "Chicken, broilers or fryers, dark meat, thigh, meat only, raw",
   "ndbno": "05096",
   "ds": "SR"
  }]
 }
};

var res = result.list.item.map(function(elem) {
  return elem.ds;
})
console.log(res);
```

Comment: But he's not trying to access anything inside `item`.